# How to set correct roles for login users

Tags: parse-platform

I am trying to set roles with parse.com
My aim is to set role to get all the data only for login users.
can you please proved step by step how should it be done with parse.com,
I tryed to play with it and read the tutrial but I am all the time getting accecss to data even if I am not logined.
thnx for helping!

Comment: Explain what you've tried. Is the data owned by one user or any logged in user is fine?

Comment: I have a user and anther class data. I want that only this user can see the data. like login user can see only his related data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create your data object you should be adding an ACL to it, created with the current user and limiting read and write to that user. This is done before you save the data object. You don't need to use a role. A role would be used where you had a group of users who all needed access, then you would add the users to the role and create the ACL for the role instead of a user.

Comment: 10x the issue was chace on ionic and not the BE